# Help with Nouns vs Verbs

Tags: verbs, nouns, conversational-deletion

What is the difference between saying "Pleasure to" vs. "Pleased To"
Is it better to use nouns or verbs? What rings better?

Comment: Please provide a context

Comment: Do you mean, in the context of "I am pleased to meet you" vs. "It is a pleasure to meet you"?  Both are fine, I don't think there's any significant difference between them in this formal greeting.  In a different context a verb might be better than a noun, but you'd have to give me an example of something you find confusing.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! I guess I am trying to better understand in what contexts is it better to use a verb vs a noun? I guess "pleased to" implies a more personal experience that it is something that you do and "pleasure to" would denote a more general context for someone reading?

Comment: Im not great at explaining what Im trying to say :/

Comment: I may be wrong on this, but I think "pleased" in the sense of "I am pleased to meet you" is an adjective, not a verb. And "pleased to meet you" might be slightly more common, but both are acceptable (my impression is that "pleasure to meet you" is more chiefly British English, and even there it varies depending on regional dialect and not seen as often in modern English as "pleased")

Answer (score 1):

Both greeting formulas are short for longer ones, where predictable strings have been omitted.

- *Pleased to meet you*
  is short for
  ***I am*** pleased to meet you.
- *Pleasure to meet you*
  is short for
  ***It is a*** pleasure **for me** to meet you.

> This happens a lot in spoken English. There are so many required strings of pronouns, auxiliaries, and prepositions marking constructions that the ones that can be expected at the beginning of the sentence usually get slurred over or just dropped. The phenomenon is called [**Conversational Deletion**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299).

In this case, you can see that *pleased* is a predicate adjective with *I* as its subject,
while *pleasure* is a predicate noun in an extraposed sentence with dummy *it* as its subject.

Comment: Ahh yes! "Pleased" is definitely not a verb but an adverb/predicate adjective. Thank you all for the input. I am more clear now about how either structure comes off to a reader.